# Can an application wipe or corrupt a SD card?

Tags: external-sd

Is it possible for apps to eliminate or corrupt SD Card specifically the apps that are installed from Play Store? Lately my micro SD card got wiped out on its own and I couldn't recover any of my data since I formatted it as the default disk to write earlier on my phone. I also wonder if it is possible for Beta version of apps to distort an SD Card

Comment: This isn't impossible but rarely happens. Apps with android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS are able to format external sd cards or those with android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE can erase files from external storage. Also apps with root access can do almost everything they want. But it hardly makes sense to erase data unless one has clearly destructive intentions. Usually the data loss is associated with some malware activities or hardware failures.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible for an application to maliciously wipe or potentially corrupt data on a SD card. However, that is very unlikely to happen.

More likely is that the SD card had some sort of hardware failure.